# How to tell what's causing drawRect to be called?

Tags: cocoa, debugging, nsview

I've got my custom NSView with a bunch of custom buttons in it, the buttons are added as a subView in the NSView's drawRect method.

Now I'm finding that after pressing a button the drawRect of the parent view is repeatedly called. Sometimes it only stops when I quit the app - I know this from a simple log statement in drawRect.

Now I know there are probably bigger architectural issues in my app causing this, where do I go to begin tracking down what's causing this view to be repeatedly redrawn?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't be adding subviews in `drawRect:`.

Are you doing any custom drawing or are you just adding subviews? If you're not doing any drawing, you should not implement `drawRect:`.

You want to add the subviews in `initWithFrame:` and then you want to set the frames of the subviews in `layoutSubviews` based on `self.bounds`.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

**EDIT:** Just realized that you were asking about NSView and not UIView. I've never used NSView, but perhaps they work similarly.

**EDIT 2:** I read a bit about NSView and it doesn't seem to have `layoutSubviews`. Perhaps you should set the frames in `drawRect:`? I'm still pretty sure you don't want to add subviews in `drawRect:`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for your answer - I hadn't realised I was abusing drawRect. I've moved the adding of the subviews out and am ensuring it's only being called when necessary and it's all working well now.