# Is there any way to tell what causes a -drawRect: message to be sent to an NSView?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, drawrect, appkit

I am having inconsistent behavior in my app, where sometimes a draw call isn't received by `MyView`, even after following the same steps where it is received.

The thing is, in the backtrace for `drawRect`, there are no frames that tell me what is happening within our code that causes the message to be sent

Here is an example backtrace (top 2 frames don't matter):

```
2   MyApp                               0x00000001000112a5 -[MyView drawRect:] + 1429
3   AppKit                              0x00007fff8bfc87be -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursive:displayRectIgnoringOpacity:inGraphicsContext:CGContext:topView:shouldChangeFontReferenceColor:] + 1331
4   AppKit                              0x00007fff8bfc8156 __46-[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) drawLayer:inContext:]_block_invoke + 242
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8bfc7caf -[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) _drawViewBackingLayer:inContext:drawingHandler:] + 2403
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8bfc7341 -[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) drawLayer:inContext:] + 108
7   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff88045b19 CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 3494
8   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff88044d6d ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 59
9   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff88044759 _ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev + 1565
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8bfc6318 _NSBackingLayerDisplay + 641
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8bfb8878 -[_NSViewBackingLayer display] + 818
12  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff880364a5 _ZN2CA5Layer17display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 603
13  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff88035fcd _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 35
14  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff880354a1 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
15  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff880350ec _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 508
16  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff88040977 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 71
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff88f3efc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff88f3ef37 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff88f1de58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 328
20  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff93726935 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
21  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff9372676f ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
22  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff937265af _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
23  AppKit                              0x00007fff8be5fdf6 _DPSNextEvent + 1067
24  AppKit                              0x00007fff8be5f226 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 454
25  AppKit                              0x00007fff8be53d80 -[NSApplication run] + 682
26  AppKit                              0x00007fff8be1d368 NSApplicationMain + 1176
27  MyApp                               0x000000010000d102 main + 34
28  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8ec5c5ad start + 1
```

I just want to figure out if it's possible to see exactly what message/event that's happening that results in the `-drawRect`, so I can see why `-drawRect` is occasionally not being received

Note that I have seen this thread:[How to tell what's causing drawRect to be called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375128/how-to-tell-whats-causing-drawrect-to-be-called), but it doesn't answer the question I have

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I know I said the top 2 frames didn't matter, but turns out they did.

Just a brain fart, I had set the breakpoint 3 stack frames deep, and if I had just set it in `drawRect`, I would see that it is in fact being called every time I expect it to.  There was an if statement in the 2nd stack frame that prevented execution into the top stack frame that I was breaking on when writing this question T.T